# Publish WPF + EF Core App with Windows Installer Project

Tags: sql-server, wpf, installation, entity-framework-core

I have tried to create an .exe file to my WPF App and SQL Server related databse with EF Core using Windows Setup Installer Project.

I included all the dll's files from /bin/Release and built it for any CPU.
The Setup Project has been created successfully and it worked on my PC as I expected.

Otherwise when I try to install the Setup File on another PC, I can't even open it up and see what's wrong.

I guess the problem comes from the database but I can't find anything helpful on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you get the application installed, run it and nothing happens, right?  Here is what you do:

1. Run it.  Watch nothing happen
2. Hit the Windows key and type "Event"
3. When "Event Viewer" appears in the list of applications, run it
4. In Event Viewer, go to `Windows Logs >> Application`

Near the top there will probably be an error entry.  It will probably be related to your application.  And if you were missing a key file needed to run your application, like a DLL, the name of the file will probably be in there in the details section

5. Go back to your installer and add that missing file.  Or if that file is part of some support package (like, say, MS Redistributable for Visual C++) then add the installer for that too.